# How to prepend a value to an array inside the object of state in Reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, setstate

I have an initial state as:

```
this.state = {
         transition:{
         completedStages:[]
         }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is, at a function call I can update my state for `completedStages`, such that every time the state is updated the value is prepended in the array. Like:

```
this.state = {
         transition:{
         completedStages:[SR, RR, BR]
         }
}
```

For this, what I tried is:

```
let completedStages = [...this.state.transition.completedStages];
    completedStages.unshift('SR');
this.setState({
             transition:{
             completedStages:[completedStages]
             }
})
```

This is messing up my output and giving every added array value in pair of other as key. How can I understand this scenario?

Comment: appended or prepended?

Comment: prepended, yes ofcourse, as I am using `unshift`, I have updated that word

Comment: Can you please show the state which results from your code and explain how that differs from what you want?

Comment: Unshift should work fine here. The reason its getting mucked up is `completedStages` is an array, yet when you set in state you are inserting that array into a new array, via `[completedStages]`. Don't put `completedStages` in an array since it already is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just prepend it like this. You can use the function way of setState either:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  transition:{
  completedStages:['SR', ...prevState.transition.completedStages]
}})
```

Comment: But that would add it in end.. I need this to be pushed in beginning, every new value to be pushed inside at biggining

Comment: Sorry, I missed it. Prepend also works with deconstruction. I edited my answer.

Comment: That worked like a charm... Can you help me undersrand it .. for my future reference?

Comment: Some explanation:

`['foo', ...oldArray]` creates a new array instance, without mutating the `oldArray`.

`this.setState(function(prevState){return {count: prevState.count +1};})` is the functional way of setState to generate a new state from old one.

And the the simplified ES6 version of the inner function part will look like: `prevState => ({count: prevState.count + 1})

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
this.setState((state) => {
   return {
     transition: {
       ...state.transition,
       completedStages: ['SR', ...state.transition.completedStages]
     }
   }
})
```